# REGEXP_SUBSTR() select before string

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

I selected string with uppercase RED and this works good

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2   ( SELECT 'we saw a RED apple on the big tree' str FROM dual)
  3  SELECT str,
  4  REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^(RED]+') before_str
  5  FROM data;
STR                                BEFORE_STR
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
we saw a RED apple on the big tree we saw a
```

But when I selected with lowercase, I do not get the results I want

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2  ( SELECT 'we saw a red apple on the big tree' str FROM dual)
  3  SELECT str,
  4  REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^(red]+') before_str
  5  FROM data;

STR                                BEFORE_STR
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
we saw a red apple on the big tree w
```

How can I get results that I would not use in capital letters?

If I wanted to use the function on some rows in the table, I would not get the desired results

Comment: `[^(red]` means match any character that isn't `(`, `r`, `e` or `d`. This fails quickly on the first word that contains a forbidden character (an e). Try looking into a negative capture group instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `'i'` for case-insensitive matching. Having said that, your REGEXP is incorrect... `[^(RED]+` will match all characters until one of `(`,`R`,`E`,`D` is found.

You could use `REGEXP_INSTR` to locate the position of match and `SUBSTR` to extract the substring:

```
WITH DATA AS( 
    SELECT 'we saw a red apple on the big tree' str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'we saw a RED apple on the big tree' str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'we saw something' str FROM dual
)
SELECT str, SUBSTR(str, 1, REGEXP_INSTR(str, 'RED', 1, 1, 0, 'i') - 1) before_str
FROM data;
```

Result:

```
| STR                                | BEFORE_STR |
|------------------------------------|------------|
| we saw a red apple on the big tree | we saw a   |
| we saw a RED apple on the big tree | we saw a   |
| we saw something                   | NULL       |
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to add a space before and after your keyword else you'll get BEFORE_STR returned where it is only PART of a word. Here a capture group is used to get the first part where all characters are followed by the case-insensitive keyword surrounded by spaces. Note REGEXP_SUBSTR returns the original string if the match is not found.

```
SQL> WITH DATA(str) AS(
       SELECT 'we saw a red apple on the big tree' FROM dual UNION ALL
       SELECT 'we saw a RED apple on the big tree' FROM dual UNION ALL
       SELECT 'we saw something'                   FROM dual UNION ALL
       SELECT 'we saw a redbird on the big tree'   FROM dual
   )
   SELECT str, REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '^(.*?)( RED )', 1, 1, 'i', 1) before_str
   FROM data;

STR                                BEFORE_STR
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------
we saw a red apple on the big tree we saw a
we saw a RED apple on the big tree we saw a
we saw something
we saw a redbird on the big tree

SQL>
```